# c lang - different array length by pointer

Tags: c, arrays

I have problem with my own function for get array length.
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a[] = {5,4,1,2,1}; //len -> 6!! FAIL! WHY?
    //int a[] = {5,4,1,2}; //len -> 4 OK!
    int len = 0;
    int *p = a;
    while(*p != '\0'){
            printf("%d\n", *p);
            len++;
            *p++;
    }
    printf("len: %d\n", len);
    return 0;
}
```

code above output:

```
5
4
1
2
1
32767
len: 6
```

but this array int a[] = {5,4,1,2}; - produce len = 4 - ok.

why it happens?

Comment: This is undefined behavior. An array does not have a null-terminator.

Comment: A C string is an array. But that is not a bijection: An array is not a C string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because there's no `0` at the end of your array. It's not added automatically, you need to do it explicitly. As a result, you accessed outside the array, which results in undefined behavior. The fact that one of your tests seemed to work was purely luck, you can't depend on it.

```
int a[] = {5, 4, 1, 2, 1, 0};
```

The only time that C automatically adds a null terminator is when you use a string literal to initialize a `char` array, e.g.

```
char c[] = "abcde";
```